# Finding basis and dimension of a matrix that is not homogeneous?

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem states:

Solve the given system of equations using matrix operations and give the dimension of the solution space.

$x-2y+2z=3$

$-2x+y+2z=1$

The RREF form that I got is:

\begin{bmatrix} 
      1 & 0 & -2 \\ 
      0 & 1 & -2 \\ 
   \end{bmatrix}

The next step is to solve for x and y, which are the basic variables, and I got

$x=2z-5/3$

$y=2z-7/3$

So, my question is, is this the right equation?
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}
= s
\begin{bmatrix} 
2\\
2\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix} 
-5/3\\
-7/3\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the basis?
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
2\\
2\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix} 
-5/3\\
-7/3\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If not, would it be just 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}
= s
\begin{bmatrix} 
2\\
2\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: It can’t be the last expression you’ve written since $(0,0,0)^T$ is not a solution to the original system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option is the correct one.

We have the equation as
$$\pmatrix{1&-2&2&|&3\\-2&1&2&|&1}$$
You can carry the right hand sides with the row reduction (just consider the row operations acting directly on the equations). We indeed obtain 
$$\pmatrix{1&-2&2&|&3\\0&-3&6&|&7}\ \leadsto\ \pmatrix{1&0&-2&|&-\frac53\\0&1&-2&|&-\frac73}$$
which directly translates back to
$$x-2z=-5/3\\y-2z=-7/3$$
This justifies the first option you gave.
Note, however, that it's *not a linear* subspace, just an *affine* one, i.e. it's a translation (by $(0,-\frac53,-\frac73)$)  of a linear subspace (the line $(2,2,1)s$), so its dimension is $1$.